# Open WinForm in Code view

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I used Visual Studio 2013, It is easy to open design view or code view of a winform. Like this

[image]

But now I upgrade to VS 2015, I can only right click on winform then choose Code view or press F7 to switch from design to code view

[image]

Is there anyway to open code view as VS 2013 in VS2015?

Comment: Your VS2015 install is borken.  You'll have to spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: @HansPassant Can your VS2015 open code view without rightclick or press F7?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Here is a screenshot of my VS15.  If I rightclick on the highlighted line, it brings up the option to open either the code view or the design view.  I tend to agree with Hans, I think your install may be damaged.

[image]

Comment: And if I double click on the parent Form10.cs line, it brings up the design view.